# Rephrasing "patient with suspected cancer"

Tags: prepositions, collocation

Is it possible to form a sentence like

> A patient who is suspected *for/with/??* cancer

and if so, what is the correct preposition after suspect?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking if a verb can be replaced with a preposition, so probably should be asked on [ell.se].

Comment: Why the down votes?

Comment: @Clueless: Would you consider editing your example to something like [*"A vehicle which was suspected of having a faulty transmission"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22suspected+of+having+a+faulty+transmission%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)? I would certainly vote to reopen in that case, and it would do away with objections to user76732's answer (I do not consider *suspected* to be "specialised medical terminology", so I think it's the downvote rather than the answer which is irrelevant, but it's surely better to simply avoid that being an issue in the first place).

Answer (score 2):

The problem with any of these constructions is that being "suspected of" something is usually perceived as perjorative. It's the cancer that is suspected, not the patient. I would drop "suspected" altogether. How about "a patient believed to have cancer"?

Comment: -1 That is unrelated to the language issue at hand. "Suspected" is a medical term with specific meaning and usage that has its purposes. Whether to use *suspected* or not is out of the purview of the question.

Answer (score 1):

The preposition *of* is often used in such a construction.

> A patient (who is) suspected ***of*** cancer

*Clinical examination of a **patient suspected of cancer** of the uterine cervix* <sup>[1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/13905108)</sup>

*Given knowledge of the likelihood of a high test value occurring in a patient with cancer compared to the likelihood of a high test value occurring in a **patient suspected of cancer** that was later ruled out, …*  <sup>[2](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=spsD4WQbL0QC&pg=PA752&lpg=PA752&dq=%22patient%20suspected%20of%20cancer%22&source=bl&ots=T-608Kqm1d&sig=eztDvTkRNtXejonn05DjJ3TvQ4k&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yUx7U8T1FtG1kAXb54CwCw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22patient%20suspected%20of%20cancer%22&f=false)</sup>

*… various tests that a **patient suspected of cancer** may have to undergo …* <sup>[3](http://mediconweb.com/cancer/how-cancer-is-diagnosed/#.U3k0eHaH_cg)</sup>

This construction uses ellipsis and generalizes.

Comment: Given that Google Books returns 5620 hits for [*"suspected of **having** cancer"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22suspected+of+having+cancer%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but only 2190 hits for [*"suspected of cancer"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22suspected+of+cancer%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), I take it that "This construction uses ellipsis" means "The word **having** is elided".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, and its derivations/alternatives ('generalizes').